# Reverse chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

It is easy to use Chain Rule to solve this exercise, but how can we express $\partial f/ \partial x$ interms of $\partial f/ \partial \rho$, $\partial f/ \partial \theta$ and $\partial f/ \partial \phi$?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to invert the equations
$$
x=\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z=\rho\cos\phi
$$
So notice that
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2\left(cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi+\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\right)\\
=\rho^2\left(\left(cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\right)\\
=\rho^2\left(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\right)=\rho^2\\
$$
Since we know $\rho\geq0$, this gives us $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Now
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}=\frac{\rho^2\sin^2\phi\left(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)}{\rho^2\cos^2\phi}=\tan^2\phi
$$
Since when $z\geq0$ we have $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$ and when $z\leq0$ we have $\frac\pi2\leq\phi\leq\pi$, we obtain $\phi=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}z$. Similarly $\theta=\arctan\frac yx$. So on inverting these equations we get
$$
\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\phi=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}z\\
\theta=\arctan\frac yx
$$
Now we can use the chain rule to evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho},\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi},\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$. For example,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\\
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho}\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}}\frac 1z\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\frac1{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\frac{-y}{x^2}\\
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\frac1{x^2+y^2+z^2}\frac{xz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\frac y{x^2+y^2}
$$
Substituting $x,y,z$ in terms of $\rho,\phi,\theta$, we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho}\cos\theta\sin\phi+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\frac{\cos\theta\cos\phi}{\rho}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\frac{\sin\theta}{\rho\sin\phi}
$$
You can similarly find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

Comment: your explains with mine are synergic

Answer (score 1):

It should be
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}.
$$

And similarly
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y},
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}.
$$